# How to pass a predicate as parameter into IActionResult in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, predicatebuilder

I want to refactor my huge messy code and am stuck. I have an IActionResult Index which makes a simple Select on a Table. Later I added two different searchpanels, which are pretty complicated and were inside the Index. I used PredicateBuilder for that. Now I have excluded them from my Index and put them in two separate IActionResults, which are called by the user:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Func<model,bool> predicate)
    {
        IQueryable<model> SQL;
        SQL = from m in _context.model
              select m;
        if(predicate != null)
            SQL = (IQueryable<model>)SQL.Where(predicate);

        return View(await SQL.ToListAsync());
    }

public IActionResult Search1(Parameters parameters)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<model>();

        predicate = predicate.And(s => s.Number1 == parameters.Number1);
        predicate = predicate.And(s => s.Number2 >= parameters.Number2);
        ...
        
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { predicate = predicate });
    }

public IActionResult Search2(string searchString)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<model>();

        predicate = predicate.And(s => s.publisher1.Contains(searchString.Trim()) || s.publisher2.Contains(searchString.Trim());
        ...
        
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { predicate = predicate });
    }
```

The problem is, that when I go now to my Index Page, the Homepage simply doesn't work anymore. As soon as I remove Func<model,bool> predicate as parameter the Homepage runs as usual.
So does that way not work in general, or did I do something wrong?

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Is there any error in browser console?

Comment: Only "The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature."

Comment: RedirectToAction cannot redirect with complex type data, it only can redirect with simple type data like string, int etc. I suggest you can use Session or TempData to store the data.

Comment: Thank you for this useful information! So I guess, that it is not possible to set this complex type data as a parameter. I try it with TempData.

Comment: I checked it out, but unfortunatelly I see no solution right now for that... TempData: like u said it is a complex data, so TempData didn't work neither. So I tried it with TempData and Json, which leaded to an endless loop. Session: It needs a String to store and can't parse predicate to it... Global Variable could work in a way, but another user could mess up the result... Maybe you can suggest sth else? But thank you for your help